# How to implement Box.net v2 Authorization process using OAuth 2.0 in application back-end?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, box-api

I am using OAuth 2.0 for Box.net Authorization.
I am not getting any way to obtain Access Token programmatically(Without User Interaction).
Is there any alternative to achieve this from application back-end?

Comment: Are you looking to get access to a Box user's account? Or do you just want to have access to anonymous information?

Comment: Access to a Box user's account. once I request for the authorization code, It prompts me to enter box.net account credentials. I want to make this authorization process running from back-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole idea of OAuth2 is that the user has to "grant" or "deny" your application access to the resources that you are asking to gain access to.  Unlike the old wide-open world where the user might just give you their account password so you could use it to login to their account, and assume you're not going to change anything important (like their password), OAuth2 wants the user to sign into the website for themselves, and have the website know that your app now has some limited amount of access to their account.

The other upside, besides better security (not perfect security), is that if the enterprise uses LDAP / Active Directory / Tivoli / Kerberos / Shibboleth / Okta then whatever crazy 2 (or 4 or 6) factor authentication hoops the user has to go through, your application doesn't need to know how to jump those hoops.

The only cases where this is extended is for administrators, who have access to some amount of information across their enterprise account.  However; They still have to sign-in to a Box account to give the application access to their admin capabilities via OAuth2.  The assumption is that Admins would be more careful about which applications they sign into.

Maybe you are building an internal application for a big Box customer.  Have the admin sign-in to their Box account through the OAuth2 flow.

If you're just automating something with a script, then have the user sign-in once, and store the Access Token and Refresh-Token in a keystore.  Treat them like passwords.